# Delete S3 objects or buckets from localstack (and also from recorded_api_calls.json)

Tags: localstack

I am using localstack in app development for local development and automated testing.
When using S3 I found that the recorded_api_calls.json just keeps growing, even if I run a cleanup job or delete the bucket I am using all together.
For testing that is not a problem, as we use throw-away containers - but for local development the data is more 'valuable' to work with a multitude of different configurations and I don't want to erase the recorded_api_calls.json all together.
Is there a way to make the deletion from S3 (and the recorded_api_calls.json backend) work as expected?

Ideally I could just use our app cleanup task that deletes from S3, but if need be I can also delete one bucket completely.

Cheers, Chris

Comment: Try deleting the data directory and/or (if using docker and container is stopped `docker container purge`)?

Comment: @JohnMee Thanks for the suggestion - but I was looking for a way to keep some of the data - I only want to get rid of the contents (and payload/runtime penalty) of one S3 bucket - especially I want to keep the contents of the other bucket and DynamoDB content.